# Replacing single value in dict in python list comprehension with other items

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, networkx

Currently I am populating a generator from `networkx`'s `MultiDiGraph` module, in this way:

```py
new_u0_edges = ((u, new_u1, key, edata) for u, v, key, edata in
                self.g.edges_iter(u0, data=True,
                keys=True) if v == path[0])
```

But I would also like to update a single `key, value` pair in the `edata` dict, specifically `edata['label']`. The slow way of doing this with lists instead of generators is:

```py
new_u0_edges = ((u, new_u1, key, edata) for u, v, key, edata in
                self.g.edges_iter(u0, data=True,
                keys=True) if v == path[0])
for u, new_u1, key, edata in new_u0_edges:
    edata['label'] = u0[0] + new_u1`
```

FYI, `u0` and `new_u1` are both strings. Yes, this is a deBruijn graph in case you're interested.

My question is: *Is there a way to modify this `edata` dict in the generator?* `dict.update([iterable])` doesn't return a value as necessary for a generator, and list comprehensions don't seem to allow for reassigning.

Thanks!

Update: Some example variable data (still testing so it's silly looking):

```
u0 = 'DEFGHIJ'
new_u1 = 'EFGHIJKLMNabcdefghiwxyz012345'
key = 'rna'
edata = {'color': '#E41A1C', 'seq_type': 'rna', 'fontcolor': '#E41A1C', 'weight': 1, 'label': 'DEFGHIJK (nreads=1)'}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a list comprehension? You are updating mutable values in a list, **not** producing a *new* list.

Comment: For someone who's strugeling with scientific terms, posting the variable data would be nice so a mortal could take a look at it :)

Comment: The final goal is to add these new edges to the network and remove the old ones, so I suppose I *am* creating a new list. I wanted to use a list comprehension generator because I will potentially have many new edges to add to the `MultiDiGraph` `self.g` and `MultiDiGraph.add_edges_from` is faster with an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function to do the processing for you, then call it to generate each element from the generator.  You could also utilize `yield` to write your own generator function rather than trying to cram it in to a generator statement.

Comment: Thanks @sr2222! This is probably the most Pythonic way, and certainly the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

`((u, new_u1, key, edata) for u, v, key, edata in
                self.g.edges_iter(u0, data=True,
                keys=True) if v == path[0] and not edata.update({'label':u0[0]+new_u1}) )`

I think would work ... although its pretty gross